# Error with Provisioning Profiles (no matches) in Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

I am trying to build/run my Xamarin.Forms (PCL) on my iPhone for testing and debugging. I'm suddenly getting the following error:

> No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile...

As you can see from the image below, the profile it's looking for is available on the Mac in the right spot. I cleared out all my other profiles (distribution,et al), and started clean with a single profile. I'm still getting the error. I've tried changing app identifiers and back, creating a new profile, cleaning/rebuilding package, and restarting VS, Mac, and PC.

Any help/assistance would be greatly appreciated. I'm at a total loss here, and am trying to get some bug fixes out for the app.

[image: screenshot shows matching provisioning profiles on mac and VS]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is talking about the signing identity, not the provision. It's likely that you have one or more of the following errors on your Mac:

- No certificate (signing identity) that can be used with that provision
- A previous certificate has expired and can't be used now
- There is a certificate, but it does not have the private key

Open up Keychain.app and look under the Certificates menu. You should have something like:

```
iPhone Distribution: My Name
```

It might also say `iPhone Developer`, depending on what type of certificate it is. If you see the one you expect to work with that provision, check that it's a.) Not expired. It will be red and say expired. b.) Has a public and private key. You should be able to expand it to see both.

If any of those is the issue, you will have to recreate a new signing identity (certificate) from http://developer.apple.com (go to the Member Center -> Certificates). Then, you need to edit the provision in there to work for that newly created certificate and re-download it. After downloading both new files, click on them to open them and then check Keychain.app again and verify. You should be able to select it VS afterwards (Restart VS) too in the Signing Identity menu, and then the correct provision will be selectable too.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have any of those errors on my Mac. What ended up working for me was setting it up on my personal Mac, instead of a shared machine. I had provisioned on there before, so I'm not sure why it just stopped working. This is a great answer, so I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it working! My suspicion is that it was related to point #3. Your personal machine likely had a valid cert (signing identity) on it. You can't download that to other machines from the developer portal. Instead, you would have to export from keychain on your personal machine and import it.

Comment: Hi ,I.m also facing the same issue from yesterday.I tried creating new certifictes.signing identity and provisioning profile can be selected in ios bundle signing page.But its showing Error: No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile while running the application in release mode.

Comment: +As I am checking,certficate for that distribution provision is added.I am not using an expired certificate and it has a private key in key chain..............................I could run the application in debug mode by using the development certificate I have added,facing issue in release mode which uses distribution certificate.

Comment: should we have a public key,I am having private key not a public key!!!why so?

Comment: I am getting the corresponding distribution provision profile after selecting the signing identity in bundle signing page. But still, I am getting * No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile* error after running my application in release mode.can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Change profile in VS project setting to "Automatic". Also verify type of your profile Development/Production

Comment: I tried that, but it gave me a different error. I deleted and reinstalled my development certificate, and now I'm getting a different error:
`No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain`. I have the signing key in my keychain.

Comment: check this: there many recommendations https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30824/no-valid-ios-code-signing-keys-found-in-keychain-when-trying-to-debug-using-iphonesimulator and https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4129/no-valid-iphone-code-signing-keys-found-in-keychain-error