# No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

When take xamarin ios release i get error,

```
No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile '1xxxxxxx-
xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Actully my first release in another mac machine. Is any problem for using same signing identity and provisioning profile in both machines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with Provisioning Profiles (no matches) in Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40429229/error-with-provisioning-profiles-no-matches-in-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix this problem in Xcode first .

Than only you can expect it to work in Xamarin , so first create a sample project in Xcode try to run it .
if everything works fine there it will also work in Xamarin provided you select suitable developer profile and provision profile in options .

If it doesn't work in Xcode project too , you are supposed to export p12 from the Mac where you created these certificate to the Mac you are working now and install it .

Comment: > _it will also work in Xamarin provided you select suitable developer profile and provision profile in options_ It's not always true.

Comment: What problem u get ??

Comment: The subject. Xcode works with selected provision profile, but Xamarin fails with the same signing config. As always, recreating provision profile helps.

Comment: Delete all junk certificate from keychain, and start afresh by creating new credential, better if u let Xcode do its job, then in VS Mac select the right profile and u r good to go