# No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile(xamarin ios)-tried existing solutions.issue not fixed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

[existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40429229/error-with-provisioning-profiles-no-matches-in-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2015)

*Please help

I have created an application for my client.
Created a developer account for the client.

Added this developer account to visual studio.

Application is working perfectly in debugging mode with development certificate.facing issue with distribution.

I am getting the corresponding distribution provision profile after selecting the signing identity in bundle signing page. But still, I am getting * No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile* error after running my application in release mode.

Methods I have Tried

method 1;

1.Removed existing certificate from keychain.
2.Deleted existing private keys
3.created ios distribution certificate in developer account.downloaded to the system and installed(certificate and private key is added to keychain)
4.created an app id in dev acoount.
5.dvices are added
6.appstore distribution provisioning file created
7.downloaded and installed the provisioning file.
8.In visual studio-selected signing identity and the provisioning profile in Bundle signing page.
9.Run

**error: No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile**.

method 2:'
1.created a distribution certificate in visual studio(preference>manage certificates>create distribution certificate)
2.in developer account-created distribution provisioning file
3.visual studio-downloaded all provision files.
4.select signing identity and provisioning profile
5.run
.

**getting the same error**.

can anyone help me to solve this issue.
As I am handling multiple projects I am having multiple developer accounts in visual studio.
Do we delete all the other apple accounts from the project.??

Waiting for your suggestions.

thanks in advance.

Comment: As for your method 1: Have you tried closing and restarting VS? This always does the trick on my end after adding a new profile.

Comment: i have tried this manu times.Coz I am facing this issue for the last 2 days.And I have tried it with new distribution provisional files.No change

Comment: @XamarinInfo Hi , you also can manually go to apple developer website to download the mathced 
distribution provisioning file to the Mac . And double click it to add it into KeyChain.

Comment: Hi junior Jiang,Tried that too..

Comment: Are you sure, that the bundle identifier in your Info.plist does match with the identifier entered in the developer platform?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had two valid distribution certificates with the same name.

Once I removed one from Apple Certificates and Identities, then the publish appeared to work and this error disappeared.